# Calculating standard deviation from power spectral density

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have set of data (x) for power spectral density (Gaussian white noise), and I am trying to find the standard deviation from it. The result looks wrong because I know that the standard deviation must be with a range of 5.

I used below code

```
sd=std(x)
```

[Data](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zlrl0abw3mkwo3n/AAAEw35UhkQe0wYgSST7VzJLa?dl=0)

Thanks

Comment: That code works, my guess: your knoledge of the range of std is wrong.

Comment: `std(x)` will give you the standard deviation of the spectrum amplitude. But it sounds like you want the standard deviation of the time-series signal. This questions is a math/statistics question, not a programming one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the inverse fourier transform, and look at the element at time zero. Note that this is actually just the sum of all the values (`\int{X(w)e^{iwt}}dw | t=0 = \int X(w) dw`), with some scaling constant applied which depends on how you defined the psd in a discrete frequency domain

---

The power spectral density, `S_xx(w)`, is equal to `F{R_xx(tau)}`, the fourier transform of the autocorrelation, `R_xx(tau) = E[x(t)x(t+tau)]`.

Since you want the standard deviation, you can get `R_xx(0) = E[x(t)^2]`, and then `std^2 = E[x(t)^2] -  E[x(t)]^2`.

---

Unfortunately, it seems you have no way to recover `E[x(t)]`. Perhaps you already know this is 0?